# parse data from list dictionary

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

```
NameValueList= [
                    {
                        "Name": "Modified Item",
                        "Value": "No"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Style",
                        "Value": "BIG PONY"
                    }
]
```

how can i get the second data . Output will be like this  'Style':'BIG PONY'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quite clear to me what you are asking, so here are some options:

1. You want the output to be a dictionary

```
NameValueList =  [
                    {
                        "Name": "Modified Item",
                        "Value": "No"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Style",
                        "Value": "BIG PONY"
                    }
]

output = {NameValueList[1].get("Name"):NameValueList[1].get("Value")}
OUT: {'Style': 'BIG PONY'}
```

2. You want the output to be a string

```
output = str(NameValueList[1].get("Name")) + ":" + str((NameValueList[1].get("Value")))
OUT: 'Style:BIG PONY'
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries function with `key`-`value` pairs, where the first item is the `key` and the second item is the `value`. For example, "Name" is the `key` and "Modified Item" is the `value`. In the first example, you can iterate over the `values` in the `dictionary` at index position 1 in the NameValueList.

```
for value in NameValueList[1].values():
    print(value)

#output:
#Style
#BIG PONY
```

In the second example, you can use `.get()` and pass in the `key` to get the `value` of that `key`. Note: the `key` you pass in must be of type `string`.

```
var = NameValueList[1].get("Name") + ":" + NameValueList[1].get("Value")
print(var)

#output:
#Style:BIG PONY
```